# TeamCity build agent disconnected

Tags: teamcity

I installed a build agent on Windows 7 and always have the agent show up as "disconnected". The log teamcity-agent.txt shows below information

```
 If this is the first time this agent registered on the server make sure it is     authorized by administrator in the server web UI. 
[2012-09-05 02:56:14,416]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Agent registration finished. 
[2012-09-05 02:56:14,418]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Stop command was not performed. No build to stop with reason: BuildInterruptReason.AGENT_SHUTDOWN 
[2012-09-05 02:56:14,418]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Starting agent shutdown sequence, reason: Restart agent, failed to download upgrade from server 
[2012-09-05 02:56:14,424]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Host configuration for downloading updates: HostConfiguration[host=http://myteamcity:8080] 
[2012-09-05 02:56:14,424]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Downloading http://myteamcity:8080/update/teamcity-agent.xml ==> C:\BuildAgent\temp\iQ0fjie6zR125neulJeqiYauT8zQ5zOI 
[2012-09-05 02:56:15,070]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Downloading http://myteamcity:8080/update/plugins/agentSystemInfo.zip ==> C:\BuildAgent\update\plugins\agentSystemInfo.zip 
[2012-09-05 02:56:15,747]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Downloading http://myteamcity:8080/update/plugins/amazonEC2.zip ==> C:\BuildAgent\update\plugins\amazonEC2.zip 
[2012-09-05 02:56:16,617]   INFO - agent.impl.AgentPortFileWriter - Delete agent runtime file from C:\BuildAgent\logs\buildAgent.port 
[2012-09-05 02:56:16,619]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Unregistering from build server: 18 
[2012-09-05 02:56:16,800]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Shutdown agent WebServer start 
[2012-09-05 02:56:16,801]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Shutdown agent WebServer finish 
[2012-09-05 02:56:16,801]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Shutdown agent finish 
[2012-09-05 02:56:16,968]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Downloading http://myteamcity:8080/update/plugins/ant.zip ==> C:\BuildAgent\update\plugins\ant.zip 
[2012-09-05 02:56:50,086]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Downloading http://myteamcity:8080/update/plugins/antPlugin.zip ==> C:\BuildAgent\update\plugins\antPlugin.zip 
[2012-09-05 02:56:52,070]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Downloading http://myteamcity:8080/update/plugins/assembly-info-patcher.zip ==> C:\BuildAgent\update\plugins\assembly-info-patcher.zip 
[2012-09-05 02:56:53,464]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Downloading http://myteamcity:8080/update/plugins/clearcase-agent.zip ==> C:\BuildAgent\update\plugins\clearcase-agent.zip 
[2012-09-05 02:56:55,375]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Downloading http://myteamcity:8080/update/plugins/cmake-runner.zip ==> C:\BuildAgent\update\plugins\cmake-runner.zip 
[2012-09-05 02:56:57,190]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Downloading http://myteamcity:8080/update/plugins/commandLineRunner.jar ==> C:\BuildAgent\update\plugins\commandLineRunner.jar 
[2012-09-05 02:56:58,218]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Downloading http://myteamcity:8080/update/plugins/coveragePlugin.zip ==> C:\BuildAgent\update\plugins\coveragePlugin.zip 
[2012-09-05 02:57:11,629]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Downloading http://myteamcity:8080/update/plugins/crashDetector.zip ==> C:\BuildAgent\update\plugins\crashDetector.zip 
[2012-09-05 02:57:12,436]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Downloading http://myteamcity:8080/update/plugins/cvsAgent.zip ==> C:\BuildAgent\update\plugins\cvsAgent.zip 
[2012-09-05 02:57:20,720]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Downloading http://myteamcity:8080/update/plugins/dotCover.zip ==> C:\BuildAgent\update\plugins\dotCover.zip 
[2012-09-05 02:58:00,011]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Downloading http://myteamcity:8080/update/plugins/dotNetPlugin.zip ==> C:\BuildAgent\update\plugins\dotNetPlugin.zip
```

How can I get the agent connected?

Comment: this is normal. When you install an agent(stub) it updates itself with the latest packages. You just have to wait.

Answer (score 42):

Here is a very comprehensive blog on re-connecting disconnected agents

http://michaelbarnesjr.wordpress.com/2012/10/18/teamcity-build-agent-disconnected/

Here are the steps (copied from the above link)

If an agent becomes disconnected for whatever reason, you can follow these steps to re-connect it:

- ssh to the server that the disconnected agent is on.
- go to the build agent’s bin directory (i.e. /opt/teamcity/buildagent/buildagent01/bin/)
- su to the user that the agent runs as (i.e. appBuilder)
- run agent.sh start

That will start the agent, and after a few seconds or so, the next time you go to TeamCity, it will be connected.

If Team City is running on a windows server, you can connect to that server, go to Services and restart the build agent that has become disconnected. [image: Team City]

Comment: can you follow the steps on that blog in windows? I'm trying to do it but have no idea where to start. Please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46336098/how-to-ssh-to-a-server-in-windows-7

Answer (score 17):

In my case the agent was started but listed as disconnected, after waiting several minutes it was still disconnect. So I went to the bin directory on the build agent like Peter suggested and ran the following two commands

```
./agent.sh stop
./agent.sh start
```

essentially just restarting the build agent. That did the  trick for me.

Comment: Same happened to me but under a windows machine go to the bin directory on the build agent and should run: 
`./agent.bat stop
./agent.bat start`

Answer (score 11):

First, make sure in the TeamCity website dashboard to ***authorize the agent*** if you haven't done so already.

Next, make sure the agents "ownPort" is not blocked by a firewall on the agent. This is the port that TeamCity will use to send messages to the agent. The value can be defined in "${agent.home}/conf/buildAgent.properties".

As of TeamCity 2017.2.1, the "ownPort" is not present, nor is there any embedded documentation (i.e. commented out examples). The default value is 8080, but you can just add the property and value you want like this:

```
## Defines which port the agent will use to receive messages from TeamCity.
## Defaults to 8080 if not present.
ownPort=9091
```

Comment: I found the agent is connected this morning. Looks any fresh teamcity agent needs time to refresh itself. We just need to wait it done. I did find similar situation reported from other forums.

Answer (score 3):

In my case under Windows 8 Professional:

> TC build agent upgrade failed

1. I checked out `BuildAgent\logs\teamcity-agent.log`, there was trouble with the "upgrade process".
2. I checked out `BuildAgent\logs\upgrade.log`, there were more detailed "DEBUG" messages. The problem was "access denied" on shutting down service.
3. I added the user account of the TC server service to "Administrators" to let it stop the agent service.
4. I removed the user account of the TC server service from "Administrators" user group.
5. Restarting both service (TC server + Agent) led finally to have:

   ```
   BuildAgent\logs\buildAgent.port
   ```

   file: the agent was finally connected after successfull.

Comment: Adding the account running the service to the local admins did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had issues with the server and change the port for the server.

So, the agent was unable to connect to the server since I only changed the server port and not the agent properties.

Once I updated the agent properties, the agent started working again.

The properties are found under:
TeamCity\buildAgent\conf\buildAgent.properties

The property is found like:
     serverUrl=http://localhost:8080

Answer (score 1):

Starting the TeamCity Agent manually in the Services panel resolved the issue for me (on a Windows machine).

Problem was indicated in the upgrade.log (in BuildAgent\logs directory):

```
ERROR - r.agent.upgrade.UpgradeRunBase - Failed to start agent after upgrade: java.io.IOException: Failed to start TeamCity build agent service. Please check TeamCity build agent service user have enough permissions to stop and start the service.
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem when working remotely over VPN and my IP address changed.  In the conf/buildAgent.properties file, I changed my assigned IP for the serverURL property to use localhost instead, and the agent connected right up.

```
## The address of the TeamCity server. The same as is used to open 
TeamCity web interface in the browser.
#serverUrl=http://111.222.333.444:8111
serverUrl=http://localhost:8111
```

Comment: In my case I update the server url because the port of server changed and works!!!

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue on Windows 10, when I changed the port of TeamCity from "8111" to "80".

To fix this issue, I opened the file `C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\conf\buildAgent.properties` and chenged the first line from `serverUrl=http\://localhost\:8111` to `serverUrl=http\://localhost\:80`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to connect agent through various steps.

1. try to find agent service by navigation to services.msc from "win + r". then check if service is start or not if not then start the service.

Now if this don't work then try step 2.

2. navigate to agent directory, which is where you've installed agent. Then go to bin where you can see several bat file like "service.start", "service.stop" , etc.
   Now run the "service.start" bat file .

I hope this will resolve you issue.